# Repeated rows in join between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following code:

```
SET LINESIZE 2000;
SET PAGESIZE 20;
COL column_name FOR A40
col CONSTRAINT_NAME for a30;
COL CONSTRAINT_OWNER FOR A20;
col SEARCH_CONDITION for a35;
SELECT A.OWNER||'.'||A.TABLE_NAME||'.'||B.COLUMN_NAME "COLUMN_NAME",B.POSITION,A.OWNER "CONSTRAINT_OWNER",A.CONSTRAINT_NAME,CASE CONSTRAINT_TYPE
WHEN 'P' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY'
WHEN 'C' THEN 'CHECK CONSTRAINT'
WHEN 'U' THEN 'UNIQUE KEY'
WHEN 'R' THEN 'REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY'
WHEN 'V' THEN 'CHECK OPTION - VIEW'
WHEN 'O' THEN 'READ ONLY - VIEW'
END AS CONSTRAINT_TYPE,SEARCH_CONDITION
FROM DBA_CONSTRAINTS A left JOIN DBA_CONS_COLUMNS B
ON A.CONSTRAINT_NAME=B.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE A.OWNER = 'SOE'
AND A.TABLE_NAME = 'INVENTORIES'
--AND A.CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'CCAR_01_UK'
ORDER BY POSITION
/
```

But the output is bringing repeated rows:

```
COLUMN_NAME                                POSITION CONSTRAINT_OWNER     CONSTRAINT_NAME                CONSTRAINT_TYPE       SEARCH_CONDITION
---------------------------------------- ---------- -------------------- ------------------------------ --------------------- -----------------------------------
SOE.INVENTORIES.PRODUCT_ID                        1 SOE                  INVENTORY_PK                   PRIMARY KEY
SOE.INVENTORIES.WAREHOUSE_ID                      1 SOE                  INVENTORIES_WAREHOUSES_FK      REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY
SOE.INVENTORIES.PRODUCT_ID                        1 SOE                  INVENTORIES_PRODUCT_ID_FK      REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY
SOE.INVENTORIES.PRODUCT_ID                        1 SOE                  INVENTORY_PK                   PRIMARY KEY
SOE.INVENTORIES.WAREHOUSE_ID                      1 SOE                  INVENTORIES_WAREHOUSES_FK      REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY
SOE.INVENTORIES.PRODUCT_ID                        1 SOE                  INVENTORIES_PRODUCT_ID_FK      REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY
SOE.INVENTORIES.WAREHOUSE_ID                      2 SOE                  INVENTORY_PK                   PRIMARY KEY
SOE.INVENTORIES.WAREHOUSE_ID                      2 SOE                  INVENTORY_PK                   PRIMARY KEY
SOE.INVENTORIES.WAREHOUSE_ID                        SOE                  INVENTORY_WAREHOUSE_ID_NN      CHECK CONSTRAINT      "WAREHOUSE_ID" IS NOT NULL
SOE.INVENTORIES.QUANTITY_ON_HAND                    SOE                  INVENTORY_QOH_NN               CHECK CONSTRAINT      "QUANTITY_ON_HAND" IS NOT NULL
SOE.INVENTORIES.QUANTITY_ON_HAND                    SOE                  INVENTORY_QOH_NN               CHECK CONSTRAINT      "QUANTITY_ON_HAND" IS NOT NULL
SOE.INVENTORIES.WAREHOUSE_ID                        SOE                  INVENTORY_WAREHOUSE_ID_NN      CHECK CONSTRAINT      "WAREHOUSE_ID" IS NOT NULL
```

Can someone help me? the tables are [ALL_CONS_COLUMNS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-5B08133E-40D0-4A9E-9033-BFCC1493BA3F.htm#REFRN20045) and [ALL_CONSTRAINTS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-9C96DA92-CFE0-4A3F-9061-C5ED17B43EFE.htm#REFRN20047) from documentation

Comment: Why don’t you use distinct on your select

Comment: I've already tried. I get
ERROR at line 8:
ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype in column SEARCH_CONDITION

Comment: Got it. How important is it to get the “search_condition“ column in your output? Can you do away with that column & use distinct for your case? The reason I ask is because Long data type in Oracle has lot of restrictions.

Comment: Just add `and a.owner=b.owner`

Comment: In addition, in actual supported oracle versions there is `search_condition_vc` which is varchar2 column

Answer (score 0):

I assume these are the Oracle sample databases/tables? If so then those are not the standard constraints so I'm guessing that you/someone has been adding/amending them? If that's the case it looks like something has been done incorrectly so I would drop them and re-apply them - if necessary